# guardar imagen en django python

Tags: django, django-models

Hola me gustaría saber si puedo y como posiblemente, guardar una imagen un una carpeta cuyo nombre sea el que e ingresado en el **titulo** del mismo modelo por ejemplo:

**titulo** = "animacion"

**imagen** = esta se almacenara en uploads/animacion/

```
class Imagen(models.Model):
"""Models add Imagen.

.. versionadded:: 3.0

"""
titulo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
imagen = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esta idea, crear una función que gestione como se guarda el archivo.

En tu caso quedaría de este modo:

```
models.py

def cambiar_ruta_de_fichero(instance, filename):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('uploads', instance.titulo)):
        pass
    else:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join('uploads', instance.titulo))
    return os.path.join('uploads', instance.titulo , filename)

class Imagen(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    imagen = models.FileField(upload_to=cambiar_ruta_de_fichero)
```

Comment: voy a probarla y mas tarde te paso el dato

Comment: Buenas @NEFEGAGO , te funciono bien?

Comment: Gracias amigo @CecilioAlonso   la probé y funciona a la perfección he realizado unos pequeños cambios en tu respuesta para que sea completamente funcional al copiar y pegar en cualquier models.py gracias eres muy amable

Answer (score 1):

**1.-Configurar tu settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**2.- Configurar tu archivo urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # tus urls
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**3.-Definiendo tu models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Documento(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    documento = models.FileField(upload_to='documentos/')
    subido_a = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**4.-Definiendo tu forms.py**

```
from django import forms
import *.models 

class DocumentoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documento
        fields = ('descripcion', 'documento', )
```

**5.-Define tu views.py**

```
def mi_metodo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')#redirigue a donde deseas
    else:
        form = DocumentoForm()
    return render(request, 'mi_template.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

**6.-tu template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Subir</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Regresar</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

este ha sido lo que me ha funcionado, claro no es el unico metodo puedes hacerlo sin los FORMS, con AJAX, en fin...

**Nota.-**

`upload_to='documentos/'` aqui defines donde deseas guardar la carga.

Espero te ayude !!